# Why not show class css in email when using mail() php send mail to gmail?

Tags: php, html, css, email

Why not show class css in email when using mail() php send mail to gmail ?

I test send email by this code to hotmail it's show like this in email

[image]

But when i test send email by this code to gmail it's show like this.

[image]

It's not show class='button' as same as hotmail how can i do that ?

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$to      = "some_mail@gmail.com";
$subject = "test email";
$message = "

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
    <style type='text/css'>
    .button{
        color: #a7a7a2;
        background: green;
        padding: 2px 14px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;font-family: \&quot;Helvetica Neue\&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;'>
        <table align='center' style='margin:auto;'>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class='button'>
                        <a href='test.php' target='_blank' style='padding: 11px 0px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#000; font-size:16px; text-align:center; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold'>TEST BUTTON</a> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: EXAMPLE <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: return@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@example.com');
?>
```

Comment: try `bgcolor` or `background-color` in your css instead of `background`

Comment: @Chris - i tested but not work too , thank you ^^ may be gmail not generate class like hotmail and yahoo ?

Comment: Maybe it's better to style the `a` directly and not the `td`?

Comment: @Chris --- but i have to use class in td. how can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail does not support embedded css in the head tag. But you can try this:

```html
<html>
        <body style='margin: 0; padding: 0;font-family: \&quot;Helvetica Neue\&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;'>
            <table align='center' style='margin:auto;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <style scoped>
                         td {
                           color: #a7a7a2;
                           background: green;
                           padding: 2px 14px;
                           border-radius: 10px;
                         }
                       </style>
                       <td>
                         <a href='test.php' target='_blank' style='padding: 11px 0px; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#000; font-size:16px; text-align:center; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold'>TEST BUTTON</a> 
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The above applies a style to the child `td` and not the whole document.

Comment: like add style to td tag ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking